# a question about memorized lazy eval macro in scheme language

Tags: macros, scheme, lazy-evaluation

Currently, i have been reading the book [the scheme programming language](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/) written by Kent Dybvig.

In section [5.7](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/control.html#./control:h7), it implements memorized lazy eval in scheme using the scheme macro system.

The source code as

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ expr) (make-promise (lambda () expr))]))

(define make-promise
  (lambda (p)
    (let ([val #f] [set? #f])
      (lambda ()
        (unless set?
          (let ([x (p)])
            (unless set?
              (set! val x)
                (set! set? #t))))
        val))))

(define force
  (lambda (promise)
    (promise)))
```

But i can not understand why the variable `set?` need to be tested twice in the procedure `make-promise`.
This is the  reason from the book

> The second test of the variable set? in make-promise is necessary in the event that, as a result of
> applying p, the promise is recursively forced. Since a promise must always return the same value, the result of
> the first application of p to complete is returned.

which i can not understand

Could anyone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Evaluating the promise might involve recursively forcing it, which can change `set?`?

Comment: With delayed evaluation you can basically delay in chain and that cain migh tnot be only one level but perhaps the third level points back to the first etc. Thus it might happen that calling `(p)` updates the same version `val` and it that happens then `set?` is changed from false to true and then it should not set it since it is already set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that `force` may reenter itself. Maybe an example can help you understand this:

```lisp
(define x 5)

(letrec ([f (delay
              (if (zero? x)
                  0
                  (begin
                    (set! x (- x 1))
                    (+ (force f) 1))))])
  (force f))
```

The result will be `0`, because the inner `force` call returns 0.

If without the second test, the result will be `5`. In this situation, every `(force f)` returns different values.